# Can we get the "photography" tag killed?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [photography tag](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photography) isn't helpful.

Can we get it added to the "[intrinsic/ambient tags](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/512/kill-the-unix-tag/514#514) for this site? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is done (watch out for [untagged](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions), but note that intrinsic tags does not mean "cannot be created on the site".

Comment: Hmmm. There are now some questions like this one http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2940/what-can-i-do-in-photokina which appear to be untagged but which don't show up in that list.

Comment: Well, now I went and retagged that one. Here's another that I won't mess with: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2296/what-makes-a-photo-a-good-photo  How can these be found?

Comment: @mattdm: Both of those questions appear to be tagged to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: @jrista: yes, this: http://photo.stackexchange.com/posts/2296/revisions :)